# ZSH only displaying last 16 or so commands with history. HISTSIZE & SAVEHIST are 500

Tags: history, zsh

In ZSH when I type `history` I'm only displayed the last 16 or so commands. I would like `history` to display all the existing commands in the history file.

When I look in my .zsh_history (my history file) I see all the 500 previous commands that should be there.

I looked in the man page, but I don't see anything that controls how many of the history items are listed. I also looked in my, `env` but don't see anything that could be controlling this.

Any help would be appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`history 1` (or `history 1 -1`) will display all entries from 1 (first entry) to -1 (last entry). You can also use `history 1 100` to display the first 100 entries or `history -100 -1` to display the last 100 etc.

For more information see the section on `fc` in `man zshbuiltins`. (`history` is equivalent to `fc -l`).

Comment: `alias history="history 1"` in `~/.zshrc` made my history behave as expected.

Comment: This is the right answer. I don't know why zsh history doesn't behave like this by default, but when I accidentally deleted this fix in my `.aliases` file (and I should have my dotfiles in a private repo), it took me a while to find this fix again.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is simply correct, but I would like to quote some [official documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) about this, in case it helps someone. (And this is too long for comment.) First look at `history`:

> Same as `fc -l`.

Simple enough. Now look at `fc`:

```
fc -l [ -LI ] [ -nrdfEiD ] [ -t <timefmt> ] [ -m <match> ]
      [ <old>=<new> ... ] [ <first> [ <last> ] ]
```

> The first two forms of this command select a range of events from `first` to `last` from the history list. The arguments `first` and `last` may be specified as a number or as a string. A negative number is used as an offset to the current history event number. A string specifies the most recent event beginning with the given string.

So `history 1` means `fc -l 1`, which means starting from the first entry. Similarly if you want “last n” history (`history n` in Bash) you need `history -n`. As for default value:

> If `first` is not specified, it will be set to -1 (the most recent event), or to -16 if the `-l` flag is given.

Comment: Note that `history` in Zsh is incompatible with [the same builtin in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html).

Comment: This doc can also be accessed using `man zshbuiltins`.

Answer (score 0):

The response from  Lost Odinson fixed it for me. Just set alias history="history 1" in ~/.zshrc. It saves the extra typing needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself stubmbling upon this page while looking for a solution to find the `last N commands` when using `ZSH` on `macOS` and simply wanted to share my result.

**tl;dr** for `ZSH` users who want to see the last n commands. Add this to your `.zsrhc`:

```
function historyr() {
  history -$1 -1
}
```

**Usage**: `$ history 100` # View the last 100 commands executed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer updated so it is clear how it is a bit of a supplemental answer for other users who may reach this page similar to myself.